# Sveltekit Call load function in +page.server when params change

Tags: sveltekit

My search bar component redirects the user to the search page like so

```js
const handleSearch = () => {
  goto(`/movies/search/${searchValue}`);
};
```

`src/components/searchBar`

```js
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import searchIcon from '../assets/icon-search.svg';

    export let placeholder;

    let searchValue = '';

    const handleSearch = () => {
        goto(`/movies/search/${searchValue}`);
    };
</script>

<form class=" ml-5% mt-6 pb-6 flex " on:submit|preventDefault={handleSearch}>
    <label class=" relative ">
        <input
            class=" w-full py-2 pl-10 pr-2 bg-[transparent] border-none text-text text-lg font-light caret-primary placeholder:font-light focus:outline-none "
            type="text"
            {placeholder}
            bind:value={searchValue}
        />
        <div class=" absolute top-[50%] left-0 translate-y-[-50%] ">
            <img src={searchIcon} alt="" loading="lazy" />
        </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

Then the movie gets fetched on `+page.server.js`and rendered in `+page.svelte`. Everything is fine.

`movies/search/[search_params]/+page.server.js`

```js
export const load = async ({ params }) => {
  const { search_params } = params;
  const fetchSearchedMovies = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?                                      api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-                                              US&query=${search_params}&page=1&include_adult=false`
                  );
  const data = await resp.json();
  return data.results;
};

return {
  searchResults: fetchSearchedMovies()
};
};
```

`/movies/search/[search_params]/+page.svelte`

```js
<script>

    export let data;
    const { searchResults } = data;
</script>

<SearchBar placeholder="Search for Movies" />
<CardGrid title="Search Results">
    {#each searchResults as movie (movie.id)}
        <Card {movie} />
    {/each}
</CardGrid>
```

When I trigger another search, hit enter, it changes the url `movies/search/movieYourSearchingFor`, but the content doesn't get updated, i guess because the load function doesn't get re-triggered. When I refresh the page, it then gets loaded.

So my question is how can I make the load function run again, when the search_params change?
Can I use invalidate for that? I read in the docs, but Im not sure Im understanding it right.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should automatically update, the problem is probably this line:

```js
const { searchResults } = data;
```

This causes the property to be read just once; change it to:

```js
$: ({ searchResults } = data);
```

That way the results update when `data` changes.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! 
So as a reactive element, sveltekit knows in this case that the params have changed and therefore triggers the load function to re-run?

Comment: Yes, you only need manual invalidation for things that SvelteKit cannot track automatically. (Or rather, it always updated `data` already, you just did not see it; the reactive statement propagates the update.)